# How to display success message only after sending the mail to recipient using Jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Here is my contact-us form. I used ajax post to send data. Below is the code.
**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-lg-7 well">


                        <h4 style="padding-top:8px;">Your email address will not be published. Required fields are marked <font color="red">*</font></h4>
                            <label>Name<font color="red">*</font></label><br>
                            <input class="form-control" style="height:35px;width:230px;border-radius:4px;" required type="text" name="name" id="name"/><br>
                            <label>Phone<font color="red">*</font></label><br>


        <span>

            <input id="element_4_1" name="element_4_1" class="element text" size="3" maxlength="3" value=""  type="text"> -

        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="element_4_2" name="element_4_2" class="element text" size="4" maxlength="4" value="" type="text"> -

        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="element_4_3" name="element_4_3" class="element text" size="10" maxlength="10" value=""  type="text" required >

        </span>

<br><br>
                            <label>Email<font color="red">*</font></label><br>
                            <input id="email" class="form-control" style="height:35px;width:230px;border-radius:4px;" required type="email" name="text"/><br>
                            <label for="input4">Message</label>
                            <textarea name="contact_message" class="form-control" rows="4" id="input4"></textarea>
                            <p>&nbsp;</p>
                            <button type="submit" style="margin-left:65px;"class="btn btn-large btn-info" id="button">Submit</button>

                    </div>
```

**Jquery Ajax :**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
console.log( "ready!" );
  $("#button").click(function(){
console.log("ready2");

                  $.ajax({

                    url: './contact.php',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        "name": $("#name").val(),
                        "element_4_1": $("#element_4_1").val(),
                        "element_4_2": $("#element_4_2").val(),
                        "element_4_3": $("#element_4_3").val(),
                        "email": $("#email").val(),
                        "input4": $("#input4").val(),

                    },                    
                    success: function(data){
                    $("#stage").text("Thank you for contacting us. We will get back to you shortly.");

                    }
                });
  });
});
</script>
```

**contact.php**

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors','On');
 error_reporting(E_ALL);

$name=$_POST['name'];
$phone=chop($_POST['element_4_1']);
$phone.=chop($_POST['element_4_2']);
$phone.=chop($_POST['element_4_3']);
$email=chop($_POST['email']);
$message1=chop($_POST['input4']);

if ($name && $phone && $email) { 

$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From: sales@test.com \n";
$recipient= "test@test.in";



$subject="Online Enquiry  ";


$message.="\nName                   : $name\n";

 $message.="\nPhone                  : $phone\n";

 $message.="\nEmail ID               : $email\n";

 $message.="\nMessage                : $message1\n";


 //send auto-reply
$subject_reply="Thank you for contacting";
$message_reply="Thank you for contacting us. We will get back to you shortly.";
mail($email, $subject_reply, $message_reply, $headers);


if(mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
echo "Thank you for contacting us. We will get back to you shortly.";
}
}

?>
```

Now my questions are:
1. The required attribute in the HTML form is not working . It does not show any message even when the field is empty.
2. How to display the success message in the main page when the mail is sent from contact .php. Now presently when I click submit, I get the message "Thank You", but I want it only after sending the mail to the recipient.
How can I do this.

Comment: no.. the thank you message is displayed only after the ajax requested returns a status ok...

Comment: @ArunPJohny But, I want to confirm that only after sending the mail I should get the success message. What if mail is not sent and success message is displayed.

Comment: What you are trying to do is not very good for the user experience. There could be lots of reasons for mail to not be sent within a few seconds by the mail server. During that time, do you really want the user to wait for the message to appear? It would be a better UX to just say thank you and that the user will receive an email containing something within a few minutes. If you are worried about the mail not being sent, it would be better to handle that in the code for the mailer itself. Have a flag to see if the mail has been sent or not, etc.

Comment: @Randell So you think the above code is fine

Comment: in that case you have some problem in the server side like the error handling... if the mail is not sent then it should not return a ok status... return a error status... I'm not a PHP guy so can't help you much on that

Comment: What about the required attribute. Why it is not working. I don't get to see if the required fields are empty

Comment: anyway try changing the success handler to `success: function (data) {
    if (data) {
        $("#stage").text("Thank you for contacting us. We will get back to you shortly.");
    }
}` and try

Comment: As far as I can see you're not actually checking anywhere that the required field has been filled out.  That's why it's not being enforced...

Comment: @gnack I'm using required attribute

Comment: I'm working on a larger answer for you but the short answer is the required attribute doesn't do anything by itself, you actually need to implement the validation yourself.

Comment: @gnack I'm new to this. Please tell me what I should do

Comment: @gnack - if you have a proper HTML5 doctype definition and the browser you are using supports HTML5 and the `required` attribute then you don't need to implement any validation yourself. But that's a lot of "ifs".

Comment: @StephenP exactly. The end result of what you just wrote is still: you need to implement your own validation.  You should also be validating server side.

Comment: @user3004356 Yes, what gnack said: always validate on the server even if you have full validation in the browser. Failure to validate on the server opens your web app to attack. Never trust the data coming from the browser even when you've validated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a whole lot to be addressed here.  First of all we'll start with your HTML issues as they will help to make solving your couple of problems much easier.

**Missing `<form>` tag.**   You have not wrapped your form in a form tag - do this!  Ideally you should also make the form in such a way that it will work without JS but that's an issue separate to this so we'll leave that for now.

```
<form class="contact-form">
    // REST OF HTML HERE 
</form>
```

**Missing validation.**  You've placed the required attribute which informs your code that the field should be filled out, but you haven't actually tested for this anywhere.  You can write a simple validation function like this:

```
function validate($form) {
    $form.find('[required]').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then you could call the function using this call:

```
if (validate($(".contact-form"))) {
    // Do your AJAX stuff
} else {
    // Inform the user that they have missed a field
}
```

Edit: for the record you should also perform the same validation server-side.  I've just gone with this approach as validation and best practices around said validation is a huge topic that you should probably just Google for more specific information about.

**Missing status response.** Your PHP isn't returning any kind of indication to your JS code as to what happened with the email, leaving you unable to handle any errors.  This is easily added:

```
if(mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    echo '{"status":"OK","message":"Thank you for contacting us. We will get back to you shortly."}';
} else {
    echo '{"status":"Error","message":"Email was not sent - an error occurred."}';
}
```

You can expand on this as much or as little as you like I'm just giving you a bare minimum working example here.  You would then judge the success or failure of the process in your callback in jQuery.

```
success: function(data){
    if (data.status == "OK") {
        $("#stage").text(data.message);
    } else {
        // Something bad happened, inform the user
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1: Are you sure? What browser are you using?

2: **JS Modification:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
console.log( "ready!" );
  $("#button").click(function(){
console.log("ready2");

                  $.ajax({

                    url: './contact.php',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        "name": $("#name").val(),
                        "element_4_1": $("#element_4_1").val(),
                        "element_4_2": $("#element_4_2").val(),
                        "element_4_3": $("#element_4_3").val(),
                        "email": $("#email").val(),
                        "input4": $("#input4").val(),

                    },                    
                    success: function(data){
                    $("#stage").text(data);

                    }
                });
  });
});
</script>
```

**PHP Modification:**

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors','On');
 error_reporting(E_ALL);

$name=$_POST['name'];
$phone=chop($_POST['element_4_1']);
$phone.=chop($_POST['element_4_2']);
$phone.=chop($_POST['element_4_3']);
$email=chop($_POST['email']);
$message1=chop($_POST['input4']);

if ($name && $phone && $email) { 

$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From: sales@test.com \n";
$recipient= "test@test.in";



$subject="Online Enquiry  ";


$message.="\nName                   : $name\n";

 $message.="\nPhone                  : $phone\n";

 $message.="\nEmail ID               : $email\n";

 $message.="\nMessage                : $message1\n";


 //send auto-reply
$subject_reply="Thank you for contacting";
$message_reply="Thank you for contacting us. We will get back to you shortly.";
mail($email, $subject_reply, $message_reply, $headers);


if(mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
echo "Thank you for contacting us. We will get back to you shortly.";
} else echo "There was an error. Please try again.";
}

?>
```

Comment: Could you give a link to a demo?

Comment: No I can't give u my server ip.let me see if i can create a fiddle